# Why Visual Studio C++ 2019 says SDK version not found When i have it

Tags: c++, compilation, sdk, ide

I have been struggling with my first use of Visual Studio 2019 Community and running the 1st “Hello World” Consol Application in C++.

Despite my many attempts to change VS and project configurations, I keep receiving the same error message upon building the file and after clicking running button.
Please see screenshot1  for error messages upon building: Windows SDK 10.0.18362.0  was not found, although I could find it in my local PC’s directory.
Please see screenshot2 for configuration details in Configuration manager. Error persisted even after I changed configurations:
Platform: Win 32 -> Win 64   -> same error message
Active solution configuration : x86 -> x64 -> same error message.

Please see screenshot 3 for error messages upon running: they system can not find the exe in the path specified. Though I can find my exe file (TestCells.exe)  in a similar path.
Please see in screenshot 4 fhat even after I changed configuration in configuration manager, the same errors persisted.
Please see in  screenshot 5, 6 that I can locate Windows Kits and Windows Performance Kits in my PC, and in screenshot ,7 and 8  I  tried to add in System environment variables the path of Windows Kits and Windows Performance Kits. But neither will remove the errors.
Can someone please help ? Thank you very much!

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenshot4]
[image: screenshot5]
[image: screenshot6]
[image: screenshot7]
[image: screenshot8]

Comment: The file `TextCells.exe` does not exist. I see only `TextCells.txt` which is not an executable. How do you compile and build the code? And what errors are generated at those times? Those are the images we need to see.

Comment: Please see screenshot1 for error messages upon building: Windows SDK 10.0.18362.0 was not found, although I could find it in my local PC’s directory

Comment: error messages upon running: they system can not find the exe in the path specified.

Comment: is there anything else you need to see ?

Comment: I built by ctrl+ B on the project name and ran the program by clicking green triangle button on the top

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is I had the same issue: my project that previously built okay, wouldn't build anymore and some upgrade caused it.
The way it got fixed was I downloaded a copy from github of the library and it then updated the Visual Studio with the required SDK's.
Now it all works again!